# Noncommutative finitely generated algebras need not be noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

I would like to understand an example (of the title) given in the book "An Introduction to Noncommutative Noetherian Rings" by K. R. Goodearl, R. B. Warfield...

On page 8, Exercise 1E, an example of a noncommutative finitely generated algebra is given and we need to show it is not noetherian:

[image]

My question is, following the given hint, how does one show that each $e_i \in R$ ? That is, how to write it as a combination of $s$ and $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $e_1=1-st$. Can you write the others? What is $1-s^2t^2$?

Comment: I see how $e_1=1- s \circ t$ does the job.  So if you are implying that $e_2 = 1- s^2 \circ t^2$, then $e_2(v_1)=v_1 -0 = v_1$, so doesn't work, as we should get zero.

Comment: I did not imply that. I **asked** what it is.

Comment: Ok, it's $e_1 + e_2$! Brilliant. So in general for $k>1$ we have $e_k := (st)^{k-1} - (st)^{k}$ ?

Comment: I don't know. Have you checked?

Comment: Yeah I guess I checked. Well that was brilliant, thank you Mariano very much.

Comment: Since $R$ is not commutative, $(st)^k\neq s^kt^k$ for many $k$'s. So the right formula should be $e_j=s^{j-1}t^{j-1}-s^jt^j$. It can be proved by induction, as one knows $e_1=1-st$.